# SharePoint - How do you ACTUALLY apply a Composed Look with PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, themes

There are numerous articles that explain how to create a SharePoint Composed look. They also claim to apply said composed look but they are really just applying a colour palette theme.

[Example](https://reshmeeauckloo.wordpress.com/2016/08/30/apply-theme-and-create-composed-look-csom-and-powershell/)

Applying a theme with SPWeb.ApplyTheme() does not apply a master page (only colour palette/font/logo).

Is there a way to apply a composed theme with powershell or C#?

I've successfully applied a colour palette (with ApplyTheme() and Master Page (with MasterUrl/CustomMasterUrl) but when I go to "Change The Look" it does not indicate that the correct Composed Theme is selected (it shows the default blue is selected).

Comment: Please post code and screenshots so that the community can try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right with what you discovered, and I ran into the same thing as well. Essentially you need to update the "Current" Composed Look to match the field values of your Composed Look that you applied via ApplyTheme() and MasterUrl/CustomMasterUrl:

```
#Set URL variables
$urlForSite = "https://YourSharePointSite/sites/test"
$themeUrl = "/sites/test/_catalogs/theme/15/YourTheme.spcolor"

#Get the site
$site = Get-SPSite $urlForSite
$relativeUrl = $site.ServerRelativeUrl
if ($relativeUrl -eq "/") {
    $relativeUrl = "" #make sure it doesn't end in a slash
}

#Update the "Current" entry if there is one
$designList = $site.GetCatalog([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DesignCatalog)
$camlQ = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$camlQ.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>Current</Value></Eq></Where>"
$items = $designList.GetItems($camlQ)
if ($items.Count -eq 1) {
    $item = $items[0]
    $item["MasterPageUrl"] = $relativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master"
    $item["ThemeUrl"] = $themeUrl
    #Include these if you need to
    #$item["ImageUrl"] = ?
    #$item["FontSchemeUrl"] = ?
    $item.Update()
}

#Dispose because you know you should
$site.Dispose()
```

I also found that when you apply a Composed Look via the "Change the look" option in the UI that it appears to use the DesignPreviewSaveData class when/after generating the preview:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.designpreviewsavedata_properties.aspx

When this preview is generated there are two properties that are added to the SPWeb's property bag:

- DesignPreviewLayoutUrl
- DesignPreviewThemedCssFolderUrl

I found that I didn't need to update these properties but you may want to just to go through the same steps that the UI process does.